# TypeORM behavior difference on different OS (uuid creation)

Tags: mysql, typeorm

I use TypeORM + MySQL and here code that i try to compiling on **MacOS** and on **Ubuntu 20.04**.

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  public readonly id!: number;
```

On **MacOS** result in table is being next: **field 'id' with type varchar(36)**

The same result expected on **Ubuntu**, but result is being next: **field 'id' with type char(36)**

The project is the same. Is this a system incompatibility issue? Can this be controlled somehow? When project started this causes the id field to be deleted from the tables, which causes an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
@PrimaryColumn({ type: 'varchar', length: 36 })
@Generated('uuid')
public readonly id!: number;
```

Comment: This provide the same result as in case with ubuntu